# Generating Images from Canvas, security exception in every browser except Firefox

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, canvas, cross-domain

I'm using Amazon::S3 for image uploading. When I use those images in canvas tag and then if I try to generate data image from canvas after that it gives me security exception of CORS request. Please guide me if anyone has idea.

All fine in Firefox.

Comment: It would be a good start to show what you're actually doing. It's likely unrelated to canvas since CORS has nothing to do with canvas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing well, but I think `fromURL` takes only three arguments applying that would cause it to work, like this

```
new fabric.Image.fromURL(source, function(fabricImg) {

    _fabricImageLoaded(fabricImg, params);

}, {crossOrigin: 'Anonymous'});
```

Answer (score 2):

We need to pass crossOrigin attribute while loading image into the canvas like following

new fabric.Image.fromURL(source, function(fabricImg) {

_fabricImageLoaded(fabricImg, params);

}, null, {crossOrigin: 'Anonymous'});

Answer (score 1):

This will fix your  issue crossOrigin: 'Anonymous'